# JSF: How can I check whether I'm in the "Restore View" phase?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

When a particular method in my managed bean gets called, I want to know whether I'm in the Restore View phase of the JSF Lifecycle. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're already on JSF 2.0, then you can check it using [`FacesContext#getCurrentPhaseId()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentPhaseId%28%29):

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW) {
    // Restore view called.
}
```

But if you're still on JSF 1.x yet, then your best resort is using a [`PhaseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) which listens on `PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW`, sets a flag/toggle/token in the request scope during `beforePhase()` and removes the it during `afterPhase()`. Let the bean's getter method check its presence in the request scope then.

That said, what exactly do you need it for? I've never had the need for such a functional requirement. Isn't the bean's constructor or an `@PostConstruct` annotated method probably a better place to do initialization stuff like this?

Comment: Im only on JSF 1.x. The reason I'm wanting to do something like this is that during the Restore View Phase, a method is called on my managed bean that I do not need to have called and it is particularly expensive. So I want to put in logic that says "If in restore view, don't do anything".

Comment: Have you considered the other way round? Checking if you're in `RENDER_RESPONSE`. This way you can just use `if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse()) {}` instead which is already available since JSF 1.0. But if the bean itself is request scoped, then I'd just put it in the constructor of the bean. Unless the bean has too much responsibilities, but that's another problem ;)

Comment: OK-- I thought of checking getRenderResponse but wasnt sure whether that would conclusively tell you whether you were in the RestoreView phase. I'll try it out...

Comment: It only returns `true` if you're in `RENDER_RESPONSE`. This phase is *always* executed once as last phase during a request, like as that `RESTORE_VIEW` is *always* executed once as first phase during a request.

Comment: @BalusC May I kindly ask you for advice with the following issue: have the same need (to skip data collection on APPLY_REQUEST phase, and perform it only on RENDER_RESPONSE phase). FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse() – works fine, but when open page for the first time – it returns false on RENDER_RESPONSE phase (checked with PhaseListener debugging). Any suggestion how to solve this? (JSF 1.x on IBM Domino XPages). Thanks in advance!